# Event broadcating: Laravel Echo fails receiving broadcasts

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher, laravel-echo

I can't make the front part of laravel Echo work with pusher. In my `app.js`:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'MY_KEY', // I use my own key.
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

Then, I build my JS with `gulp` (everything is alright). Then I run a random page of my local website (using Valet), open the web console and type:

```
Echo.channel('survey').listen('survey', function(e) { console.log('test'); });
```

Then I connect to pusher and send an event.

[image: pusher interface]

And nothing appends on my local website. No alert, no error or warning in my console, nothing I can see. Here is the debug return from pusher:

[image]

I don't know what to do to make it work, I think I've carefully read the documentation, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: did you listen for your queue `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Yes but I don't need, cause I'm just listening to pusher events, not sending event via laravel queue (I send events through Pusher's interface). I'm talking about the front side of laravel echo

Comment: can you send us the listen script at the client (blade file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sending events through pushers console you need to set the full namespace of the event. For example `App/Events/survey`. Echo adds the namespace automatically for you.

Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts under namespaces.

If you would send the event from Laravel it would use the complete namespace.